# C - execve() not returning -1 on command error

Tags: c, posix

I want to know if a command ran successfully without an error or not. I'm trying:

```
if (execve(buf, pl->argv, environ) != -1) { 
    perror(buf);
    laststatus = 1;
}
```

In cases such as "lss", I would get back -1. But cases such as "ls fs" (invalid), ls would print out an error but execve would return success.

How can I set `laststatus` to 0 or 1 when the command passed to execve executes successfully or fails, respectively.

Extra:

`buf`is the command name ('ls' for this case)

`pl->args` is a linked list of the arguments

Comment: You're going to have to `wait()` for the child in the parent. That way you can check the child's return code.

Comment: @EOF isn't `execve()` not supposed to return ?

Comment: @J.P.Quenord-Zermingore: The *function* doesn't return (if successful). The *process* will eventually terminate, returning an exit-code to its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help!

For others, I used the following which returned a non-zero if the command from execve failed.

```
    // in parent
    wait(&statval);
    if(WIFEXITED(statval)) {
        if (WEXITSTATUS(statval) == 0)
            laststatus = 0; // command in execve exited with 0
        else
            laststatus = 1; // command exited with non-zero.
    }
```